# How to convert XML into an HTML table with each row having Reject and accept button

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an assignment in which I am having an xml file containing information about new employee request. I have to show each entry of the xml in table format , with reject and accept button in front of each employee entry. When admin clicks on reject the entry should be deleted from xml file, if admin clicks on accept then entry should be stored in the table in a database.
How to proceed!!!please help

edit: I have used XSL to represent the XML in tabular format in HTML page

edit2:XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
  <reports>
    <name/>
    <email/>
    <phone/>
    <industry/>
    <message/>
    <website/>
    <engagement/>
    <urgency/>
    <type/>
    <specialization/>
    <customer_service/>
    <hr_service/>
    <mkt_service/>
    <sd_service/>
    <alliance_service/>
    <profile/>
    <suggest/>
  </reports>
  <reports>
    <timestamp>February 25, 2017, 1:05 pm</timestamp>
    <name>Rashmi</name>
    <email>rashmi.sri9@gmail.com</email>
    <phone>9900216479</phone>
    <industry>Arts and Entertainment</industry>
    <message>kjkj</message>
    <website>www.ccbul.com</website>
    <engagement>Education</engagement>
    <urgency>Education</urgency>
    <type>Implementer</type>
    <specialization/>
    <profile>/home/ccbul/public_html/dev/LocalTemp/project_detail/profile/Guideline To Use Task Manager2017-02-25_13:05:55.docx</profile>
  </reports>
  <reports>
    <timestamp>February 25, 2017, 1:10 pm</timestamp>
    <name>Rashmi</name>
    <email>rashmi.sri9@gmail.com</email>
    <phone>9900216479</phone>
    <industry>Arts and Entertainment</industry>
    <message>efef</message>
    <website>www.ccbul.com</website>
    <engagement>Education</engagement>
    <urgency>Education</urgency>
    <type>Implementer</type>
    <specialization>Chemical Process</specialization>
    <profile>/home/ccbul/public_html/dev/LocalTemp/project_detail/profile/Guideline To Use Task Manager2017-02-25_13:10:14.docx</profile>
  </reports>
</entries>
```

XSL code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <h2>Submitted Project details</h2>
  <div style="overflow-x:scroll">
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">name</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">e-mail</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Phone</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Industry</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">message</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Website</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">engagement</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">urgency</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">type</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">specialization</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">customer service</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">hr service</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">mkt service</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">sd service</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">alliance service</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">profile</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">suggest.</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="entries/reports">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="email" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="industry" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="message" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="website" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="engagement" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="urgency" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="type" /></td>

      <td><xsl:value-of select="specialization" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="customer_service" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="hr_service" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="mkt_servic" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sd_service" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="alliance_service" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="profile" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="suggest" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Javascript code in html page

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("/data/xml/project_detail/project_detail.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just do it :) You should at least try something before posting here.

Comment: @PascalMeunier till now I have used XSL to represent XML in table format on an HTML page, after this I am stuck

Comment: Can you paste the code here? I'm sorry but I can't help, there is too many things involved ... How do you intend to delete the item from the XML file? What language are you planning to use for the task? XSL will only format the XML to suite your visual needs, in order to manipulate the data you will need a "server-side" script.

Comment: @PascalMeunier planning to use php

Comment: Then paste your code so we can take a look at what you have done so far. You will basically need an `XML parser` and the rest if very easy to be done with PHP. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp

Comment: @PascalMeunier above code is what I have done so far